# Order by on a tag system

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a tagging system on my site and clicking on a tag will take you to a list associated of items associated with that tag. I want to order these items(batsmen) on the highest avg 'rating' score they have been given by users who have reviewed them, so the top rated batsmen associated with the tag shows first. How would i do this?

My tables:

Batsmen : id, name, Country_id, Reviews: id, rating, comment, Batsmen_id tag: id, tagname Batsmen_tag(many to many table): batsmen_id, Tag_id

Currently i am just finding all on tag($id) in my Tag controller and using a foreach with the relationship to bring back batsmen related to that tag, for example.

Current TagController code that brings back batsmen and HTML: controller:

```
    public function show($id) 
    { // $tag = Tag::find($id);

 return view('tags.show')->withTag($tag);
 }
```

html:

```
@foreach($tag->batsmen as $tags)

@endforeach
```

This is how i am getting back batsmens not related to the tag and how i order them on highest AVG:

```
$Batsmen = Batsmen::where('approved', '=', 1)
->leftJoin('reviews', 'reviews.batsmen_id', '=', 'batsmen.id')
->select('batsmen.*', DB::raw('AVG(ratings) as ratings_average' ))
->groupBy('id')
->orderBy('ratings_average', 'DESC')
->get();
```

So how do i incorporate the two and pull back batsmen related to the tag and order them by highest average?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could eager load the batsmen in your controller:

```
$tag = Tag::with(['batsmen' => function ($query) {
    return $query->where('approved', '=', 1)
           ->leftJoin('reviews', 'reviews.batsmen_id', '=', 'batsmen.id')
           ->select('batsmen.*', DB::raw('AVG(ratings) as ratings_average' ))
           ->groupBy('id')
           ->orderBy('ratings_average', 'DESC');
}])->where('id', $id)->first();
```

Comment: this comes back with a syntax error after the order by, any ideas?

Comment: @dionarap add a semicolon..my bad ;)